# How to configure SqlDataSource to handle a return value from Stored Procedure

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatasource

I have a listview and in the listview `Update` commmand I am attempting to set the parameters defined in my `SqlDataSource UpdateParameters` property. When `Update` command fires, I recieve an error message stating

> Procedure or function 'MyStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@ReturnResult', which was not supplied.

Here's the aspx with the SQL DataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlDataForCustomers" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GS_ConnectionString %>" 
    CancelSelectOnNullParameter="False"
    SelectCommand="usp_WDE_Get_DG" 
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
    UpdateCommand="usp_WDE_Save" 
    UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" >                    
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="GID" Type="Int32" />                     
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="Order" Type="Int32" />   
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="PID" Type="String" />   
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>         
        <asp:Parameter Name="PID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ProID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="GID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DGapID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEntryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEntrySetID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEntryResult" Type="String" Size="250"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DEServiceDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserLoginID" Type="String" Size="50"/>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserPersonID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ServiceDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DGRowId" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="SRowId" Type="Int32" />   
        <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="RetResult" Type="Boolean" DefaultValue="True" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="RetMsg" Type="String" Size="50" DefaultValue=""/>         
    </UpdateParameters>
```

Here is the ItemUpdating event of the LV in the code behind:

```
Sub CustomersGroupedByDataField_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles CustomersGroupedByDataField.ItemUpdating

        Dim rowValue As Integer = e.ItemIndex
        Dim DataGapTypeBeingUpdated As String = CustomersGroupedByDataField.DataKeys.Item(rowValue).Value.ToString()

        Dim boolTest As Boolean
        boolTest = True

        GetRowValues(DataGapTypeBeingUpdated)



        CheckOOS()

        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("PID").DefaultValue = intPID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("ProID").DefaultValue = intProID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("GID").DefaultValue = intGID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DGapID").DefaultValue = intDGapID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DEntryID").DefaultValue = intDEntryID.Value

        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DEntrySetID").DefaultValue = intDEntrySetID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DEntryResult").DefaultValue = strDEntryResultValue
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DEServiceDate").DefaultValue = CDate(dtServiceDate.Text)
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("UserLoginID").DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(Session("LoginID"))
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("UserPersonID").DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(Session("PersonID"))

        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("ServiceDate").DefaultValue = CDate(dtServiceDate.Text)
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("DGRowID").DefaultValue = intDGapRowID.Value
        sqlDataForCustomers.UpdateParameters("SRowID").DefaultValue = intSRowID.Value




    End Sub
```

I'm at a loss as to how I should specify the return value as a parameter?

How to handle the Return value (RetResult & RetMsg)?

Thanks for looking,

Answer (score 0):

There is a direction attribute of select parameters that marks an input parameter as a reference parameter. The same property is accessible in your code.

```
<SelectParameters>  
    <asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Name="MyReturnParameter" Type="Int32" />  
</SelectParameters>
```

After the command executes you can retrieve the value using parameter.Value or bind it to a ui element.

Comment: Are you saying that I should update my SelectParameters property to handle the Return value from the stored procedure of the UpdateCommand?
They are 2 different procedures, the SelectCommand and UpdateCommand.

Comment: Sorry, you need to add @ReturnResult as a ReturnValue parameter to your update command.

Comment: I added the following lines to the code behind.. but still receiving the error message: "Procedure or function 'MyStoredProcedure' expects parameter '@ReturnResult', which was not supplied.                                               sqlDataGapsForSelectedPatients.UpdateParameters("RetResult").DefaultValue = True
        sqlDataGapsForSelectedPatients.UpdateParameters("RetMsg").DefaultValue = String.Empty

Comment: You need to set the Direction. UpdateParameters.Direction=Input|InputOutPut|Output....see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.parameter.direction(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip...I did have a Direction value for the Parameter property but I changed it to "Output" and I am now seeing an error message:  "Procedure or function 'MyStoreProc' has too many arguments specified." Even after removing the lines of code that I just inserted, sqlDataGapsForSelectedPatients.UpdateParameters("RetResult").DefaultValue = True sqlDataGapsForSelectedPatients.UpdateParameters("RetMsg").DefaultValue = String.Empty .... From what I read, it may have something to do with the LV that I am binding to

Answer (score 0):

```
I think you can find your solution here,
https://forums.asp.net/t/1049910.aspx?How+to+get+return+value+or+output+value+from+stored+procedure+with+sqldatasource+control+

In order to get the return value you need to declare a return paramater in sqldatasource... something like this



<InsertParameters>
Your Parameters
<asp:Parameter Direction="ReturnValue" Type="Int16" Name="ReturnValue" />
</InsertParameters>



Then you need to override sqldatasource's Inserted event like this ( here you can get the return value)


protected void SqlDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
Response.Write(e.Command.Paramaters["ReturnValue"].Value);
}
```